# How to install Eclipse IDE on linux?

Tags: linux, installation, eclipse, ide, offline-files

How to install **Eclipse IDE** on linux machine, from an off-line package obtained from eclipse  ?

I got Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x64.

Comment: Usually, eclipse installation is just unzipping the archive. Also, you need a JRE (and JDK if it's Eclipse for java language)

Comment: [Home/Eclipse Wiki/Eclipse/Installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) has complete instructions